# Sample from a distribution function in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an array.

```
array([1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,0.96227599,0,
0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,1,0,0,
1,1,1,0,1,
1,1,0,1,0,
0,1,0,0,1,
0,0,1,1,1,
1,1,0,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,0,0,0,
1,0,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
0.94795539,0.85308765,0,0,1,
1,1,0.9113806,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
1,0,1,1,0,
1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,0.20363486,0.50635838,0.52025932,
0,0.34747655,0.50147493,0,0.4848249,
0,0.88495575,0,0.27620151,0.3981369,
0,0,0])
```

Values ​​range from 0 to 1.
How can I plot a probability distribution function? And then fill a table with 1000 rows based on it, where each row has 5 columns. In fact, fill the table with samples of 5 values:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `pdf` from your samples you could use a `kernel density estimator`.
One option is the [`gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) form `scipy.stats`.

> It includes automatic bandwidth determination. The estimation works best for a unimodal distribution; bimodal or multi-modal distributions tend to be oversmoothed.

Your samples look strongly bimodel with clusters at 0 and 1, so you might be better advised to use `sklearn`s [`KernelDensity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html). Here you have more control over the specific `algorithm`, `kernel` and the `bandwidth`.
Sklearn also has an introduction to [Density Estimation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html)

The workflow with both methods is quite similar:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.96227599,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
              1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.94795539,0.85308765,0,0,1,1,1,0.9113806,1,1,1,1,
              1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.20363486,0.50635838,0.52025932,0,0.34747655,0.50147493,0,0.4848249,0,
              0.88495575,0,0.27620151,0.3981369,0,0,0])

kde1 = stats.gaussian_kde(a)
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y1 = kde1.pdf(x1)

kde2 = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.1).fit(a.reshape(-1, 1))
y2 = kde2.sample(10000)

kde3 = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.01).fit(a.reshape(-1, 1))
y3 = kde3.sample(10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1, c='b')
ax.hist(y2.ravel(), bins=100, density=True, color='r', alpha=0.7)
ax.hist(y3.ravel(), bins=100, density=True, color='m', alpha=0.7)
```

[image: kde]

Note that this method those not limit your pdf on values between [0, 1].
You have to take care of this yourself ie by filtering those out in a second step. However if you choose a small bandwith you scould come pretty close.

---

I do not quite understand the second part of your question.
If you want to draw new samples from the estimated distribution you can do so via `kde.sample()` (sklearn) / `kde.resample()` (scipy). And filling those values into a table is a different question for which you definitely will find answers here on StackOverflow.